# Is it possible to get a value from append/html function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Html Code

```
<div id="price-tag"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i> <span id="price"></span></strong></div>
```

have a java script function that append value to a span

```
$("#price").html(Price);
```

Now I want to get the price value -
java script code

```
document.getElementById('price-tag').onclick = function(e){

alert(document.getElementById('price').value);
}
```

its returning undefined.
is there any way to get the value?

Comment: `span` elements do not have a `value` property, those are elements related to user input. If you want the internal html of the element, use `.innerHTML`. If you only want the text content, your `.textContent` instead.

Comment: use `document.getElementById("price").innerHTML`

Comment: And if you're using jQuery, **use** jQuery. Use `$('#price').val()`, not `document.getElementById('price').value`, although in your case you want `.text()` or `.html()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`span` is not an `input`, hence it haves no `value`. You should work with it's `innerText` as you are dealing with element's text content:

```
$("#price").text(Price);
var price = $("#price").text();
// Or
document.getElementById('price').innerText = Price;
var price = document.getElementById('price').innerText;
```